# What are the X,Y coordinates of round beads strung along an Archimedian spiral of string?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I have a commercial application for which I have simplified the underlying mathematical problem to the following:

There are 32 spherical beads on a string, each of diameter 'd'.
Each bead is touching its adjacent neighbours on the string.
The string is arranged such that it follows the path of an Archimedian spiral
I.e. The spiral is defined in r(θ) = p + qθ where p and q are some real numbers. The parameter q determines the spacing between successive turnings of the spiral, while p determines the starting position of the spiral near the origin.
The first bead on the string is assumed to be at (0,0).
The second bead on the string is assumed to be at (0,d).

How do I find the Cartesian (X,Y) coordinates of the centres of the rest of the 32 beads?

Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Nicholas Lee

Comment: I would be surprised if there were an easier way than doing it numerically.

Comment: Where is the third bead? That sets the gap between wraps of the spiral. If it touches the first two, you will wind up hexagonal, not a spiral.

Comment: The third bead will be touching the second bead, but not (generally) touching the first bead.
Likewise, the fourth bead will touch the third bead, but not (generally) touching the first or second beads. [and so on]

I think this puts limits on the minimum size of 'q', which is the distance between the spiral's turns. I think it needs to be bigger than d, or the beads can't be fitted onto the spiral at all.